# Stop page scroll after the page reaches certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can scroll be prevented after scrollTop reaches certain value say 150.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
    if($(window).scrollTop() >=50)) {
       return false;    // basically don't scroll       
    }
});
```

Comment: the `.scrollTop` set the scrollHeight using `scrollTo` function. It doesn't scroll from x to y, It just goes to y. So basically you cannot stop the scroll as your event will be called after it is set to y. You can probably set the desired scrollHeight inside the handler after comparing the height.     `if($(window).scrollTop() >=50) { $(window).scrollTop(0); }` - **Note:** using it on an element is bearable, but on window object will be annoying to the user. Above is just to show how it works. Try scrolling in >> http://jsfiddle.net/KwgMj/ << and See how annoying it can be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `.scrollTop` set the scrollHeight using `scrollTo` function. It doesn't scroll from x to y, It just goes to y.

So basically you cannot stop the scroll as your event will be called after it is set to y. You can probably set the desired `scrollHeight` inside the handler after comparing the height.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >=50) 
{ 
    $(window).scrollTop(0); 
}
```

**Note:** using it on an element is bearable, but on window object will be annoying to the user. Above is just to show how it works.

Try scrolling in >> http://jsfiddle.net/KwgMj << and see how annoying it can be.

Comment: by setting value more than 0 the scrollbar doesn't shake.

Comment: @Raminson Technically It can go till 50px but then it was just to show the OP that having a scroll and disabling scroll can be annoying to the user.

Comment: yes, you are right, preventing user from scrolling is very annoying.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {   
    if($(window).scrollTop() >=50)) {
      $(window).scrollTop(50)
    }
});
```

Comment: @user1184100 try updated answer you can change the value of the scrollTop manually.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the obvious question; why would you want this?

I would suggest another approach.

Have a wrapper which fills the entire window, have a certain height and use `overflow-x: hidden` in css.

This may and may not be what you're after though.

If you wish to make a continuing site that allows you to keep scrolling for the next step, I'd suggest you to simply `.slideDown()` relevant content.

The scroll is a really basic function which shouldn't be modified with for no good reason.

**EDIT:**
For a ipad specific solution, use a wrapper:

```
<? if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')): ?>
<!-- If iPad, add style -->
<style type="text/css">
    div#wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
<? endif; ?>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Content here -->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: i'm trying to prevent scrolling in ipad to fix a bug, so was checking out if scroll can be prevented thru script.